# Best reporting tool for tabular data

Tags: reporting

There is an application which can be described as reporting as well as content management system. Most of the views of the application are tabular reports which can be extracted in excel.

Can anybody suggest a tool which would be useful to handle generation of tabular reports. Sometimes there might be 10-15 columns. Also the tool should have feature to handle documents as well; meaning possibility to upload documents and share the same to the application users.

Please note that the tool may not be open sourced. If there is any licensing cost, that will also holds good.

Thanks!

Comment: For which platform you are looking?

Comment: @maulik kansara -  Application is currently based on JAVA. So, java based platform would be top in the preference

Comment: You should go with Dynamic Reports. It is an open source Java reporting tool

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Server reporting service by Microsoft and ASP.Net MVC or JAVA application for all your need.

Link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/create-a-basic-table-report-ssrs-tutorial?view=sql-server-2017

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017

SSRS is an independent reporting tool. Will work for both .Net or Java.